# Issue sending an explicit primary key value to Model.create in rails v3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I am trying to pass a primary key (id) value to my create method and it doesn't work.

Is there a way to do this in rails?

```
Category.create!(:id => 2828, :name => 'Some Category')
```

Comment: I am using it to seed(rake db:seed) some master data in master table.

Answer (score 1):

I have similar problem. I have a table with primary_key called `page_id`
I tried to do

```
SomeClass.create :page_id => 123
```

and

```
SomeClass.create :id => 123
```

and

```
obj = SomeClass.new :page_id => 123
obj.save!
```

and

```
obj = SomeClass.new :id => 123
obj.save!
```

with no luck.

Anyway, the solution was

```
obj = SomeClass.new :title => 'title', :whatever_field => 'whaver value'
obj.id = 123
obj.save!
```

Not sure why it works, but it is. Just call `id` accessor explicit. Note, the PRIMARY KEY in database is still `page_id` (I don't have `id` field at all)

Hope this helps.

Comment: id is a protected attribute and can't be mass-assigned.